# laravel 8 y ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

Estoy intentando eliminar registros con ajax y laravel 8 pero al momento de ejecutarse me muestra el siguiente error

> POSThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/EditusersController/destroy

en mi archivo web.php tengo la siguiente ruta

```
> Route::post('/user/eliminarUsuario',[EditusersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
```

la configuracion del boton es la siguiente:

```
 <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick="eliminarUsuario({{$lista->cedula}})" value="delete">
 <i class='fas fa-fw fa-trash'></i>
 </button>
```

y la funcion en jquery para que se realize el eliminado es la siguiente

```
function eliminarUsuario(cedula){
        console.log(cedula)
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'No se podra revertir esta accion!!',
          text: "DeseaEliminar el Usuario con Cedula :" +cedula,
          icon: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/EditusersController/destroy",
                data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                cedula:cedula
            },
            success:function(borrado){
                if (borrado = 1){
                    Swal.fire(
                      'Borrado',
                      'Usuario Borrado Exitosamente',
                      'success'
                    )
                }else{
                    Swal.fire(
                      'Error!!!',
                      'No se pudo eliminar el Usuario',
                      'erro'
                    )
                }

                }
            })
          }
        })
    }
```

no se si es que en la ruta que esta en el archivo

> web.php

me falta algo mas, o es la forma en que esta declarada la ruta en la

> url

del ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes corregir la url que estas enviando para realizar la eliminación desde el ajax,
ya que la que declaraste en el archivo web.php es la ruta que tienes que utilizar en el campo url del ajax de esta forma:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/user/eliminarUsuario",
            data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            cedula:cedula
        },
```